# MSAL automatic logout after 72 hours

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

It looks like MSAL logs out the user after 72 hour of inactivity. But I can't find this documented anywhere.

Can anyone confirm this? Is there a way to change this?

I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Client v4.17.1

Thank you

Comment: You could check the validity of the token (seen using the value of `ExpiresOn` of `AuthenticationResult`).

Comment: the api should have a method for refreshing the token by using your expired token